# Broadcast Address (in terms of subnetting)

Tags: networking, tcp, broadcast, subnet

I do not understand one thing: does each device have a broadcast address? I am subnetting a network and I am giving each **subnet** one broadcast address and not each **host**. Is this correct?

Comment: je rather dislike it than helping me. cool guys here on this site.

Comment: That is correct. One broadcast address per network. Check out this [IP calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) to ensure you use the right address given the subnet mask. It is explained really well on this [Cisco support forum](https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/what-is-broadcast-address/m-p/2494448/highlight/true#M236946)

Comment: Actually, there is also the Limited Broadcast Address (`255.255.255.255`) that works on all IPv4 networks. IP broadcast only works for IPv4 because it was a bad idea that has been eliminated in IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

For IPv4 networks, each subnet has a broadcast address.  Whatever the highest address is for that particular subnet is the broadcast address.

Suppose I had a network at `203.0.113.0` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0`.  With this mask, hosts on this network can have addresses `203.0.113.1` through `203.0.113.254`.  Hosts on this network wishing to send a broadcast message to all hosts on the network would use `203.0.113.255`.